# Blocking commands in a certain discord.py channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I recently added this code

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    prefix = re.findall('([;]|[-]|[=]+)', message.content.lower())
    if prefix and message.channel.id == "405815888177266689":
             await bot.delete_message(message)
```

The bot does remove the message but the bot detects the command too fast so the other bot(s) reply. I am wanting to make it where the other bots can't reply. What I'm asking is - is it possible to basically add the purge to this command to make it purge the recent 2 messages (the command + the bots reply).

Comment: It would probably be easier to forbid the `@everyone` role from those channels, then give everyone else (not the bots) a role that can read message from those channels.

Comment: Patrick Haugh thats not what i was asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  prefix = re.findall('([;]|[-]|[=]+)', message.content.lower())
  if prefix and message.channel.id == "405815888177266689":
    await bot.delete_message(message)

    muted_bots = ['bot_1_id','bot_2_id']
    async for msg in bot.logs_from(bot.get_channel("405815888177266689"), limit=4):
      if msg.author.id in muted_bots:
        await bot.delete_message(msg)
```

where after someone writes a message with that prefix and it gets deleted, it checks for the last number of messages (whatever you put the `limit` to depending on how many bots respond) and checks if whoever wrote that is in your `muted_bots` id list.

Comment: I got one more issue.... If i type any message that happens to have ; - = it removes this message.

Comment: Instead of `re.findall()` you can use `message.startswith()` and [This is why your commands don't work](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=commands%20work#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH

Comment: Well now im getting this error

````    prefix = message.startswith('([;]|[?]|[!]+)', message.content.lower())
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'startswith'
````

i get these errors anytime i type a messager

Comment: Sorry, you have to get the string value by using `message.content.startswith()` and try googling the command to see how it works because it only takes a string or a tuple of strings so `message.startswith('([;]|[?]|[!]+)` won't give you the correct result. Rather something like `message.content.startswith(';')`